# Text Render a bit noisy, even at 200 samples

Tags: blender

I can't seem to figure out how to get a sharper text render that I am using for my animation.

Here are the Things that I have tried:
1: Increasing Samples to as high as 300
2: Turning font shadow off
3: Denoising

Whatever I do, the text still has that weird greyish black outline and in my animation on youtube, it plays blurry even at 720p HD.

I see other peoples text videos and theirs are always sooooo sharp.

Please how can I improve my text render in the future?

I turned the world lighting all the way up and there is a weak lamp in the scene, albeit, far away from the text, but the world lighting should be enough i think.

[image: blurry text]

Comment: Stack Overflow is mainly for programming questions. There is a dedicated [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/). You might have a lot more answers on this website.

Comment: oh I see, thanks a lot. I though it was for all questions.